# split DataFrame column in x,y pairs, where each pair splits in different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame

```
     tube  curve                                    values
1   E88CC      0   0, 0, 25, 7, 50, 15
2   E88CC     -1   0, 0, 25, 0.7, 50, 5.5, 75, 13
25  ECC83      0   0, 0, 25, 0.7, 50, 1.15
26  ECC83   -0.5   0, 0, 25, 0.2, 50, 0.46
27  ECC83     -1   0, 0, 25, 0.02, 50, 0.08
37  ECC81     -2   50, 0, 75, 0.3, 100, 0.9
38  ECC81     -3   100, 0, 125, 0.4, 150, 0.86
39  ECC81     -4   150, 0, 175, 0.3, 200, 0.9
51  12AY7     -6   175, 0, 200, 0.05, 226.1, 0.2
52  12AY7     -7   200, 0, 226.1, 0.02, 250, 0.1
53  12AY7     -8   250, 0, 275, 0.1, 300, 0.27
54  12AY7     -9   275, 0, 300, 0.05, 325, 0.19
55  12AY7    -10   325, 0, 350, 0.06, 375, 0.21, 400, 0.47
56  12AY7    -11   350, 0, 375, 0.005, 400, 0.13, 425, 0.35
57  12AY7    -12   375, 0, 400, 0.001, 425, 0.06, 450, 0.2
```

where the column 'values' need to be split
like this, since those are X,Y values:

```
tube, curve,  x,   y
E88CC,    0,  0,   0
E88CC,    0, 25,   7
E88CC,    0, 50,  15
E88CC,   -1,  0,   0
E88CC,   -1, 25, 0.7
E88CC,   -1, 50, 5.5
E88CC,   -1, 75,  13
```

it was created like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', comment='#', sep='\r\n', names=['entire'], engine='python')
df[['tube', 'curve', 'values']] = df['entire'].str.split(',', n=2, expand=True)
df = df.drop(['entire'], axis=1)
```

where data.csv is:

```
E88CC, 123, 30, 45
E88CC, 0, 0, 0, 25, 7, 50, 15
E88CC, -1, 0, 0, 25, 0.7, 50, 5.5, 75, 13
E88CC, -2, 25, 0, 50, 0.3, 75, 4, 100, 10.1, 125, 19
E88CC, -3, 50, 0, 75, 0.3, 100, 2.9, 125, 8.1, 150, 16
E88CC, -4, 100, 0, 125, 1.4, 150, 6.0, 175, 13.5
E88CC, -5, 125, 0, 150, 1, 175, 5, 200, 12, 226.1, 21
E88CC, -6, 150, 0, 175, 0.8, 200, 4.8, 226.1, 11.7, 250, 19.7
E88CC, -7, 175, 0, 200, 1, 226.1, 5, 250, 11, 275, 18.9
E88CC, -8, 200, 0, 226.1, 1, 250, 4.7, 275, 10.4, 300, 17.3
E88CC, -9, 226.1, 0, 250, 0.8, 275, 4, 300, 9.2
E88CC, -10, 250, 0, 275, 0.8, 300, 4.2
```

Take note that pairs on the 'values' column are variable between rows.

output of df.to_dict('list'):

```
{'tube': ['E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'E88CC', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC82', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC83', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', 'ECC81', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7', '12AY7'], 'curve': [' 123', ' 0', ' -1', ' -2', ' -3', ' -4', ' -5', ' -6', ' -7', ' -8', ' -9', ' -10', ' Pmax', ' 0', ' -2', ' -4', ' -6', ' -8', ' -10', ' -12', ' -14', ' -16', ' -18', ' -20', ' Pmax', ' 0', ' -0.5', ' -1', ' -1.5', ' -2', ' -2.5', ' -3', ' -3.5', ' -4', ' Pmax', ' 0', ' -1', ' -2', ' -3', ' -4', ' -5', ' -6', ' -7', ' -8', ' Pmax', ' 0', ' -1', ' -2', ' -3', ' -4', ' -5', ' -6', ' -7', ' -8', ' -9', ' -10', ' -11', ' -12', ' Pmax'], 'values': [' 30, 45', ' 0, 0, 25, 7, 50, 15', ' 0, 0, 25, 0.7, 50, 5.5, 75, 13', ' 25, 0, 50, 0.3, 75, 4, 100, 10.1, 125, 19', ' 50, 0, 75, 0.3, 100, 2.9, 125, 8.1, 150, 16', ' 100, 0, 125, 1.4, 150, 6.0, 175, 13.5', ' 125, 0, 150, 1, 175, 5, 200, 12, 226.1, 21', ' 150, 0, 175, 0.8, 200, 4.8, 226.1, 11.7, 250, 19.7', ' 175, 0, 200, 1, 226.1, 5, 250, 11, 275, 18.9', ' 200, 0, 226.1, 1, 250, 4.7, 275, 10.4, 300, 17.3', ' 226.1, 0, 250, 0.8, 275, 4, 300, 9.2', ' 250, 0, 275, 0.8, 300, 4.2', ' 25, 60, 50, 30, 75, 20, 100, 15, 125, 12, 150, 10, 175, 8.571428571, 200, 7.5, 226.1, 6.63423264, 250, 6, 275, 5.454545455, 300, 5', ' 0, 0, 25, 2.5, 50, 5.11, 75, 8.25, 100, 12, 125, 16, 150, 20, 175, 24,', ' 0, 0, 25, 0.25, 50, 1.5, 75, 3.5, 100, 6, 125, 9.29, 150, 13, 175, 17, 200, 21.2', ' 25, 0, 50, 0.2, 75, 1, 100, 2.5, 125, 4.51, 150, 7.5, 175, 10.87, 200, 14.5, 226.1, 18.6, 250, 23', ' 50, 0, 75, 0.1, 100, 0.75, 125, 1.9, 150, 3.64, 175, 6.25, 200, 9.4, 226.1, 13, 250, 17, 275, 21', ' 75, 0, 100, 0.1, 125, 0.6, 150, 1.6, 175, 3.1, 200, 5.2, 226.1, 8.04, 250, 11.63, 275, 15.5, 300, 19.62', ' 125, 0, 150, 0.5, 175, 1.2, 200, 2.61, 226.1, 4.62, 250, 7.17, 275, 10.43, 300, 14, 325, 18', ' 150, 0, 175, 0.4, 200, 1, 226.1, 2.39, 250, 4.2, 275, 6.74, 300, 9.8, 325, 13, 350, 16.36', ' 175, 0, 200, 0.3, 226.1, 1, 250, 2.28, 275, 3.91, 300, 5.87, 325, 8.37, 350, 11.41, 375, 14.5', ' 200, 0, 226.1, 0.4, 250, 1, 275, 2, 300, 3.4, 325, 5.11, 350, 7.39, 375, 10.27', ' 226.1, 0, 250, 0.4, 275, 0.87, 300, 1.68, 325, 3, 350, 4.78, 375, 7', ' 250, 0, 275, 0.1, 300, 0.6, 325, 1.47, 350, 2.72, 375, 4.51', ' 25, 110, 50, 55, 75, 36.66666667, 100, 27.5, 125, 22, 150, 18.33333333, 175, 15.71428571, 200, 13.75, 226.1, 12.16275984, 250, 11, 275, 10, 300, 9.166666667, 325, 8.461538462, 350, 7.857142857, 375, 7.333333333, 400, 6.875, 425, 6.470588235, 450, 6.111111111, 475, 5.789473684, 500, 5.5', ' 0, 0, 25, 0.7, 50, 1.15, 75, 1.62, 100, 2.12, 125, 2.68, 150, 3.25, 175, 3.82, 200, 4.41, 226.1, 5', ' 0, 0, 25, 0.2, 50, 0.46, 75, 0.8, 100, 1.2, 125, 1.63, 150, 2.13, 175, 2.7, 200, 3.28, 226.1, 3.89, 250, 4.5', ' 0, 0, 25, 0.02, 50, 0.08, 75, 0.24, 100, 0.48, 125, 0.77, 150, 1.15, 175, 1.6, 200, 2.12, 226.1, 2.72, 250, 3.3, 275, 3.88', ' 50, 0, 75, 0.01, 100, 0.11, 125, 0.28, 150, 0.5, 175, 0.77, 200, 1.15, 226.1, 1.61, 250, 2.1, 275, 2.65, 300, 3.25', ' 100, 0, 125, 0.05, 150, 0.13, 175, 0.28, 200, 0.5, 226.1, 0.8, 250, 1.2, 275, 1.65, 300, 2.16, 325, 2.7', ' 125, 0, 150, 0.01, 175, 0.03, 200, 0.12, 226.1, 0.28, 250, 0.5, 275, 0.8, 300, 1.2, 325, 1.68, 350, 2.2', ' 175, 0, 200, 0.01, 226.1, 0.08, 250, 0.18, 275, 0.36, 300, 0.6, 325, 0.91, 350, 1.3, 375, 1.7', ' 226.1, 0, 250, 0.02, 275, 0.1, 300, 0.22, 325, 0.4, 350, 0.62, 375, 0.95', ' 275, 0, 300, 0.02, 325, 0.12, 350, 0.27, 375, 0.4', ' 25, 40, 50, 20, 75, 13.33333333, 100, 10, 125, 8, 150, 6.666666667, 175, 5.714285714, 200, 5, 226.1, 4.42282176, 250, 4, 275, 3.636363636, 300, 3.333333333, 325, 3.076923077, 350, 2.857142857, 375, 2.666666667', ' 0, 0, 25, 2, 50, 4, 75, 6, 100, 8.2, 125, 10.5, 150, 13.2, 175, 16, 200, 19, 226.1, 22, 250, 25', ' 0, 0, 25, 0.2, 50, 1, 75, 2, 100, 3.3, 125, 4.83, 150, 6.78, 175, 8.87, 200, 11.18, 226.1, 14, 250, 16.8, 275, 19.83', ' 50, 0, 75, 0.3, 100, 0.9, 125, 1.73, 150, 2.83, 175, 4.2, 200, 5.91, 226.1, 7.93, 250, 10, 275, 12.26, 300, 14.6, 325, 17', ' 100, 0, 125, 0.4, 150, 0.86, 175, 1.6, 200, 2.66, 226.1, 3.89, 250, 5.2, 275, 7, 300, 8.94, 325, 11, 350, 13.2', ' 150, 0, 175, 0.3, 200, 0.9, 226.1, 1.56, 250, 2.5, 275, 3.7, 300, 5, 325, 6.52, 350, 8.1, 375, 10.1, 400, 12', ' 175, 0, 200, 0.2, 226.1, 0.63, 250, 1.16, 275, 1.9, 300, 2.8, 325, 3.86, 350, 5, 375, 6.45, 400, 7.98, 425, 9.65, 450, 11.5', ' 200, 0, 226.1, 0.1, 250, 0.43, 275, 0.86, 300, 1.3, 325, 1.9, 350, 2.6, 375, 3.5, 400, 4.6, 425, 5.95, 450, 7.36, 475, 9, 500, 10.5', ' 250, 0, 275, 0.2, 300, 0.5, 325, 0.86, 350, 1.37, 375, 2, 400, 2.73, 425, 3.63, 450, 4.62, 475, 5.89, 500, 7.18', ' 275, 0, 300, 0.1, 325, 0.4, 350, 0.7, 375, 1.1, 400, 1.6, 425, 2.13, 450, 2.96, 475, 3.86, 500, 5', ' 25, 100, 50, 50, 75, 33.33333333, 100, 25, 125, 20, 150, 16.66666667, 175, 14.28571429, 200, 12.5, 226.1, 11.0570544, 250, 10, 275, 9.090909091, 300, 8.333333333, 325, 7.692307692, 350, 7.142857143, 375, 6.666666667, 400, 6.25, 425, 5.882352941, 450, 5.555555556, 475, 5.263157895, 500, 5', ' 0, 0, 25, 1, 50, 2, 75, 3, 100, 4.11, 125, 5.42, 150, 6.6', ' 0, 0, 25, 0.2, 50, 0.7, 75, 1.37, 100, 2.21, 125, 3.2, 150, 4.4, 175, 5.6, 200, 6.8', ' 50, 0, 75, 0.28, 100, 0.8, 125, 1.49, 150, 2.4, 175, 3.5, 200, 4.65, 226.1, 5.9', ' 75, 0, 100, 0.12, 125, 0.45, 150, 0.93, 175, 1.65, 200, 2.65, 226.1, 3.76, 250, 4.85, 275, 6.1', ' 100, 0, 125, 0.05, 150, 0.25, 175, 0.6, 200, 1.18, 226.1, 1.98, 250, 2.97, 275, 4.03, 300, 5.16', ' 150, 0, 175, 0.01, 200, 0.31, 226.1, 0.76, 250, 1.45, 275, 2.3, 300, 3.2, 325, 4.2', ' 175, 0, 200, 0.05, 226.1, 0.2, 250, 0.53, 275, 1.1, 300, 1.79, 325, 2.6, 350, 3.5', ' 200, 0, 226.1, 0.02, 250, 0.1, 275, 0.39, 300, 0.8, 325, 1.37, 350, 2.1, 375, 3', ' 250, 0, 275, 0.1, 300, 0.27, 325, 0.6, 350, 1.05, 375, 1.7, 400, 2.4', ' 275, 0, 300, 0.05, 325, 0.19, 350, 0.4, 375, 0.73, 400, 1.2, 425, 1.8', ' 325, 0, 350, 0.06, 375, 0.21, 400, 0.47, 425, 0.8, 450, 1.2', ' 350, 0, 375, 0.005, 400, 0.13, 425, 0.35, 450, 0.63', ' 375, 0, 400, 0.001, 425, 0.06, 450, 0.2, 475, 0.4', ' 25, 66, 50, 33, 75, 22, 100, 16.5, 125, 13.2, 150, 11, 175, 9.428571429, 200, 8.25, 226.1, 7.297655904, 250, 6.6, 275, 6, 300, 5.5, 325, 5.076923077, 350, 4.714285714, 375, 4.4, 400, 4.125, 425, 3.882352941, 450, 3.666666667, 475, 3.473684211']}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you!!

Comment: can you provide the DataFrame constructor of your input for clarity? Text doesn't allow to represent the real types of your data without ambiguity

Comment: edited. thank you

Comment: Can you rather provide the DataFrame constructor (once your `df` is loaded, give the output of `df.to_dict('list')`)

Comment: added. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "values" contains lists/arrays with an even number of values*, you could slice with [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html), then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
out = (df
   .assign(x=df['values'].str[::2],
           y=df['values'].str[1::2])
   .drop(columns='values')
   .explode(['x', 'y'])
)
```

* if you have strings in "values", first convert to array with:

```
import numpy as np

df['values'] = df['values'].apply(np.fromstring, sep=',')
```

Output:

```
     tube  curve      x      y
1   E88CC    0.0    0.0    0.0
1   E88CC    0.0   25.0    7.0
1   E88CC    0.0   50.0   15.0
2   E88CC   -1.0    0.0    0.0
2   E88CC   -1.0   25.0    0.7
2   E88CC   -1.0   50.0    5.5
2   E88CC   -1.0   75.0   13.0
25  ECC83    0.0    0.0    0.0
25  ECC83    0.0   25.0    0.7
...
56  12AY7  -11.0  425.0   0.35
57  12AY7  -12.0  375.0    0.0
57  12AY7  -12.0  400.0  0.001
57  12AY7  -12.0  425.0   0.06
57  12AY7  -12.0  450.0    0.2
```

Comment: i am afraid the number of pairs on the column 'values'  are variable between rows.

Comment: @Andres this is not an issue in my solution. The only prerequisite is to have **pairs** (i.e. an even number of values in each row). As you can see here, index 1 had 6 values giving 3 rows, index 2 had 8 values giving 4 rows.

Comment: As you seem to have strings I also updated the answer to show how to convert to arrays

Comment: Thank you! It works.. but the solution brings some cast issues. For instance, this line shows a funny y value rather than 10.01 which is the original value on the csv....```3   E88CC     -2 100.00000000000000000000  10.09999999999999964473```

Comment: @Andres [this is due to floating point arithmetic](/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). There is no real way around that. One option could be to `round` to the desired precision.